# Unable to access values coming from service in select option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, materialize

I am new to Materialize, I am trying to call the service with angularjs and view the values in materialize select option.

Below is my code:

```
<div class="input-field">
  {{merchantArray.length}}
   <select id="merchantssss" ng-model="merchant1.merchantId" ng-options="merchant1.merchantId as merchant1.merchantName for merchant1 in merchantArray" material-select watch>
    <option value>Choose Merchant</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

In the service I am getting the below response:

```
{"records":[{"merchantId":1,"merchantName":"BSNLs","merchantDesc":"BSNL descs","isActive":"Y"},{"merchantId":4,"merchantName":"Pioneer","merchantDesc":"B","isActive":"Y"},{"merchantId":8,"merchantName":"KFC","merchantDesc":"Test","isActive":"Y"}]}
```

I am unable to view the values in select option.

Can anyone guide me as to how I can get the values in select option.

Controller:

```
var merchantList = $http({
                           url: 'demo/api/v1/merchants',
                           method: 'GET',
                           headers: {
                                        "Content-Type": 'application/json',
                                        "X-Auth-Token": cookie
                                    },
                  })
            merchantList.success(function (data, status, response) {

                   console.log(data.records);

                   $scope.merchantArray = data.records;

                   console.log($scope.merchantArray);

             }).error(function (data, status, response) {

              });
```

Comment: what is the result of  {{merchantArray.length}} under the div??

Comment: That is just to print the array object coming from service. I have put it to my reference.

Comment: yes i know that but i want to know the result of that expression,you mentioned length of the array right,whats is that length??

Comment: i tried with ur code its working and i can see the options as bsnl,poineer,kfc

Comment: I guess you tried it with the giving static values to the $scope.merchantArray right? Its not coming when I call it with the service.

Comment: i tried with that  merchantArray given by you,but i removed "records" in it and assigned only marchent detials to that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117479/discussion-between-user123-and-sa-e).

Comment: Can you show your controller?

Answer (score 0):

Your model for select should be something else. Create a new scope variable to hold your selection

```
 ng-model="merchantSelected"
```

Comment: <select id="merchantssss" ng-change="merchantCall(merchant)" ng-model="merchant" material-select watch>
                                        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Merchant</option>
                                        <option ng-repeat="merchant1 in merchantArray" value="{{merchant1.merchantId}}">{{merchant1.merchantName}}</option>
                                    </select>